# file isn't replacing on edit in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

hi m trying to edit the files in Laravel, but when I edit the file then its name is changing according to edit in db but file isn't replacing the previous one in files folder, m using resource route for it,

controller:

```
  public function update(Request $request, $id)
  {

    $request->validate([
        'filename' => 'required',
    ]);

     $file = $request->file('filename');
     $clientName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
     $path = $file->move(public_path('files'), $clientName);

     File::whereId($id)->update(['filename' => $clientName]);

      return redirect('file')->with('success', 'Data is successfully updated');
  }
```

blade file:

```
    <form method="post" action="{{ route('file.update', $data->id) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
        @method('PATCH')
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="EditFile">Edit File</label>
          <input type="file" name="filename" class="form-control-file">
          <img src="{{ URL::to('/') }}/files/{{ $data->file }}" width="100"/>
          <img src="./images/pdf.png" class="img-circle elevation-2" alt="Pdf Image" width="50">
          <input type="hidden" name="hidden_file" value="{{ $data->file }}" />
        </div>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="edit" class="btn btn-primary input-lg" value="Edit" />
    </form>
```

can anyone find any mistake in code??

Comment: is the filename changing?

Comment: yes filename is changing

Comment: it all depends on the techniques you are applying. normally when you retrieved and displays an image, you edit and select another for update, the filename of the new image replaces the previous name in the field. the newly uploaded image in saved in a folder.

Comment: The use of `$file->move(...)` puzzles me a bit. Why not `$file->save(...)`? I wouldn't bother too much with the PHP tmp folder. It cleans itself up. You may have an issue overwriting an existing file by moving it. This could be a permission problem or typical on the internal working of PHP itself. Try to `save()` it in order to update an existing file.

Comment: @DimitriMostrey by replacing move with save it shows error:  Method Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile::save does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

U need "hidden_file" section on $request. U sending but didnt take.

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="hidden_file" value="{{ $data->file }}" />

U sending this code in form but you don't get this code on the server side
$path = $file->delete(public_path('files'), $clientName);

and add new one.

Comment: @waliair please don't post your answer in the comment section. You can edit your answer if you wish to add more information.